# XML Schema transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, schema

I am working on a client application (embedded systems), which uses XML format to exchange data and configuration with server.

I want to add some extra information in XML schema, about the processing of XML data (such as handlers or any custom action) without any side effect on server side.

For example,

```
<xs:element name="ethernet">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
        <!-- <handler>set_ethernet_address</handler> -->
            <xs:element name="ip" type="ipType"/>
            <xs:element name="net_mask" type="ipType"/>
            <xs:element name="gateway" type="ipType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In above examples comment represents that the element **ethernet** has a handler **set_ethernet_address**. This information is completely irrelevant to server side user. Moreover, this *handler* element is not part of the target XML file. In future I am planning to develop a source code generator which generate client side application code from the schema.

So the my questions are,

1. Can I add extra "processing instruction" in XML schema other than comment format?
2. Moreover, can I transform that XML schema to the new XML schema file for a server by removing client specific "processing instruction".

Thanks,
Nandkishor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is to use the xs:annotation element:

```
<xs:element name="ethernet">
    <xs:annotation>
     <xs:appInfo source="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2857369/nandkishor-biradar">
       <hander>set_ethernet_address</handler>
     </xs:appInfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ip" type="ipType"/>
            <xs:element name="net_mask" type="ipType"/>
            <xs:element name="gateway" type="ipType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really useful. One more question, can I use XSLT to schema file? I need to remove these annotation from schema file before passing to customer.

Comment: Yes, XSD is XML so you can certainly strip the xs:annotation elements using XSLT.